# Adjust size and position of positioned objects according to user resolution jquery

Tags: jquery, css, position, screen-resolution

I have a javascript driven page where I am placing user desks dynamically on a background image of a floorplan.  The problem I am running into is that the floorplan image is stretched to fit the user screen.  Now I need a way to modify the desk (div with background image) size and position to reflect the new dimensions.

What I have done is created a function to give me the adjustment ratio of the floor plan to the screen size:

```
function getResolutionRatio(){
    var width=$(window).width();
    var height=$(window).height();

    var location=-1
    //get floorplan image height and width

    var img=$("#bgImg")[0];
    if(img.naturalWidth){
        var imgW=img.naturalWidth;
        var imgH=img.naturalHeight;
        var ratioH=height/imgH;
        var ratioW=width/imgW;
        ratio={'h':ratioH, 'w':ratioW};
    }
```

This is giving me ratios of 1.2 to 1.6.  What I have tried with these ratios is to multiply or divide (tried both) the size and position of each desk.  Everything is positioned absolutely but this track is not working.

```
//makeDesk snippet - positioning function
var d = $("<div />", {
        id: "desk_" + desk.id,
        style:  "background-image:url(./images/Desks/desk" + desk.deskType + ".png);transform:rotate(" + desk.rotation + "deg)"
    }); //var d=div...

//store size and position for adjusting according to zoom capture
    d.data("height",desk.height/ratio.h);
    d.data("width",desk.width/ratio.w);
    d.data("top",desk.y/ratio.h);
    d.data("left",desk.x/ratio.w);

    d.css({'left': d.data("left") + "px", 'top': + d.data("top") + "px",
                'height': d.data("height") + "px", 'width': d.data("width") + "px",
                "font-size": + d.data("width")/2 +"px"});
//end snippet
```

I am looking for any suggestions on how to either change my code or change my approach to make this work.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you use the css property background-size?

Comment: I have tried that.  I think it is set to 100% for the desks to reflect the div size.  I know it didn't work well when used for the floorplan so I created an img tag to put it in.

Comment: why do'nt u try by css.  Instead of px unit with em or percentage unit for both (desk and floor plan).

Comment: I have played with EM some but since the desks are positioned precisely the EM measurement is too coarse.  That and the same thing happens no matter what the measurement unit is.  Also when using EM the zoom functions don't work correctly.

Comment: did u tried by using canvas  (placing images in canvas) ?

Comment: I have never used canvas.  I will experiment with that.  Does it stretch and reposition placed objects according to resolution?

Comment: Just looked up canvas element.  It looks like a lot of background code to implement dragging, and I think I would need a new canvas layer for every desk added to the mix.  I am going to experiment with it since I can resize all canvas elements at the same time o the same size and those would correspond with the image size.  Then once it's all drawn i can stretch to fit the screen. which would allow for the resolution changes.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/4rfuopyL/https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/4rfuopyL/

Comment: My Pleasure. with canvas all images inside it will treated like a single image. And for zoom u can swap image with high res images.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle.  I plan on using a new canvas for every image.  That should allow me to put a simple drag into effect by checking the x and y of mousedown and then repainting the image with a new origin according to the new mouse location.  That will give me what I need then I can play with stretching every canvas.  Hopefully with jQuery for simplicity.  Your example will be a big help.